# How to hide/show imageview in RecyclerView according to there position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a lock image in my RecyclerView and i want to hide/show it on long press..
I want to hide/show according to it position like if i do long press on first item in recycler view and click on hide it will hide the image for that item only and not for others I have tried this the problem i am facing that it only hide/show the image in the last position item.Please help me Thanks in Advance.

RecyclerViewAdapter

```
 public class RecycleViewAdapter extends 
 RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewHolder> {
 private List<FileName> fileNames;
 private Context context;
 private OnItemClicked onClick;
 String Name;
 RecycleViewHolder mainHolder;

public RecycleViewAdapter(Context context,List<FileName> fileNames) {
    this.context = context;
    this.fileNames = fileNames;
 }
public interface OnItemClicked {
    void onItemClick(int position);
}

@Override
public RecycleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) 
 {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    ViewGroup mainGroup = (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, 
    parent, false);
    RecycleViewHolder listHolder = new RecycleViewHolder(mainGroup);
    return listHolder;

  }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecycleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final FileName model = fileNames.get(position);
    mainHolder = (RecycleViewHolder) holder;
    mainHolder.title.setText(model.getShorttext());
    mainHolder.note.setText(model.getName());
    mainHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClick.onItemClick(position);

        }
    });
    mainHolder.setLongClickListener(new LongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(int position) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != fileNames ? fileNames.size() : 0);
}
public void setOnClick(OnItemClicked onClick)
{
    this.onClick=onClick;
}
public void getItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
        if (item.getItemId() == 0) {
            mainHolder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mainHolder.imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

}
```

}

RecyclerViewHolder:

```
 public class RecycleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
 View.OnLongClickListener,View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
 public TextView title;
 public TextView note;
 public CardView cardView;
 public ImageView imageView;
 LongClickListener longClickListener;

 public RecycleViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    this.note = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.note);
    this.cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
    this.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.lock);
    imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    view.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    view.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);


}
public void setLongClickListener(LongClickListener lc)
{
    this.longClickListener = lc;

}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    this.longClickListener.onItemLongClick(getLayoutPosition());
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, 
 ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menu.add(0,0,0,"Lock");
    menu.add(0,1,0,"UnLock");

}
}
```

I have found this from google to check the position On Bindview but i dont know how to implement in getItem selected

```
if (position == eventsList.size() -1){
holder.profileImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
}else{
holder.profileImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
}
```

MainActvity:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
 RecycleViewAdapter.OnItemClicked{
List<FileName> filenames;
DBhelper dBhelper;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;
ListView listView;
ImageView lock;
String name,note;
String col;
private static RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecycleViewAdapter recycleViewAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    checkFirstRun();
    //listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_filename);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    lock =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.lock);
    dBhelper = new DBhelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase =dBhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    filenames = dBhelper.getItemFromDatabase(sqLiteDatabase);
    initViews();
    if(filenames != null) {
        recycleViewAdapter = new 
       RecycleViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,filenames);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleViewAdapter);
        //listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
        R.layout.activity_main, filenames);
        //listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
    }
        recycleViewAdapter.setOnClick(this);

      //        registerForContextMenu(listView);
   /* listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            name = filenames.get(position).getName();
            note = filenames.get(position).getShorttext();
            Alert();

        }
    });*/
}
private void initViews() {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_add:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Note.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_pass:
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChangePass.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_list:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ToDo.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void Alert()
{
    View mview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_pass,null);
    final EditText mEdittext = (EditText) mview.findViewById(R.id.Epass);
    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    mBuilder.setView(mview);
    mBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


        }
    });
    mBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",null);
    mBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();
    dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String col = mEdittext.getText().toString();
            String password = dBhelper.searchpass(col);
            if (col.equals(""))
            {
                mEdittext.setError("Please fill the blank field");
            }
            else if (col.equals(password))
            {
                Intent intent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this,Note2.class);
                intent.putExtra("Name",name);
                intent.putExtra("Note",note);
                startActivity(intent);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            else {
                Toast temp = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                temp.show();
            }
        }
    });

}
public void checkFirstRun() {
    boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);
    if (isFirstRun){

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.first_run_dialog,null);
        final EditText FirstPass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Fpass);
        final Button submit = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.ok);
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setView(view);
        final AlertDialog dialog1 = builder.create();
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              col = FirstPass.getText().toString();
              if (col.equals(""))
              {
                  FirstPass.setError("Please fill the field");
              }
              else{
              savePass();
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  dialog1.dismiss();
              }
          }
      });
        dialog1.show();
        dialog1.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);



        getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit()
                .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false)
                .apply();
    }
}
public void savePass()
{
    dBhelper = new DBhelper(this);
    sqLiteDatabase= dBhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    dBhelper.storePass(col,sqLiteDatabase);
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    name = filenames.get(position).getName();
    note = filenames.get(position).getShorttext();
    Alert();
}


@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    recycleViewAdapter.getItemSelected(item);
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }


 }
```

My InterFace:

```
public interface LongClickListener {
void onItemLongClick(int position);
 }
```

[image]

Comment: You need to select few items in the list by long press & that items need to hide the image when they are selected right?

Comment: I am working with recycler view and cardview and showing database data in that view i need when user longclick on particular position the two opption appears if user click on lock option the image should show and if user click on unlock option the image should disappear the problem i am facing its only show and hide the image in last position

Comment: The problem is due to, the recycler view will recycle the items view. You have to update the view in `onBindViewHolder `. I need for which position you need to hide/show the image, then only I can give the correct code

Comment: I mean where you are tracking the locked/unlocked items positions?

Comment: that imageview is in all view..its depend on user if user need to hide the image of third postion or fourth or first..

Comment: Where you are calling the `getItemSelected`, its return type is `void`, it mean you are not getting anything, Is it `setSelectedItem'?

Comment: On my activity class.no its getitemSelected only

Comment: and y should its return a value i dont need the value of item i  just need the to be hide/show image on that position

Answer (score 3):

You need to track the locked or unlocked items position in adapter like

`ArrayList<Integer> lockedItems = new ArrayList<Interger>;`

and
adding, removing items to it.

or you can use a `Boolean` field in you model `FileName`

Actually, the thing is you need a way to identify whether the image in a given position need to be hide or show

if you know whether you need to hide/show in a given position then you can update the view in `onBindViewHolder` like

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecycleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final FileName model = fileNames.get(position);
        RecycleViewHolder recycleViewHolder = (RecycleViewHolder) holder;
        recycleViewHolder.title.setText(model.getShorttext());
        recycleViewHolder.note.setText(model.getName());
        if (model.isLocked()) { // or if (lockedItems.contains(position))
            recycleViewHolder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            recycleViewHolder.imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

**Edited**

Add a field `selectedItem` to the adapter to track the long pressed item position & store the item position on long press

```
holder.setLongClickListener(new LongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemLongClick(int position) {
        selectedItem = position
    }
});
```

And use that position in `getItemSelected` and add it to the `lockedItemsList` or add a `boolean` field in `FileName` & update its value & use it to know whether the item in the given position is locked or unlocked.

Comment: first things the image is not in Arraylist is it in cardview and second thing i need that image should hide and show on long press on recyclerview or card view

Comment: "when user longclick on particular position the two option appears if user click on lock option the image should show and if user click on unlock option the image should disappear", My question is if I give a position like 3 how did you know whether that item is in the locked or unlocked state now

Comment: I am too much confused please help i am new to android

Comment: leave the image view hide/show, how you are getting the locked items / unlocked items finally, post you activity code also, & your `onItemLongClick ` implementation is empty, how to you showing the option to lock or unlock?

Comment: i am showing the sqlite data in recyclerview and card view..i just put a lock Image in every row.and put the LongclickListner to recycler with two option lock and unlock what i need if user long press on any item two option appear if user click on lock the image should display and if user click unlock the image should hide for that item only on which the user longedpress..I hope you understand now

Comment: where is the code the showing option to the user to lock/unlock

Comment: On recyclerviewHolder onCreateContextMenu

Comment: Are the options only showing on user long press the item?

Comment: Yes..its only Showing on longpress

Comment: Anyway, that is not the right way, I don't know how it is showing only on long press though your `onItemLongClick ` implementation is empty.
Can you add a screenshot of showing options onLongPressed

Comment: i added the SS please check it out